# Is it possible to use a Case statement in a sql From clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to use a Case statement in a sql From clause using SQL 2005? For example, I'm trying something like:

```
SELECT Md5 FROM 
CASE
    WHEN @ClientType = 'Employee' THEN @Source = 'HR'
    WHEN @ClientType = 'Member' THEN  @Source = 'Other'
END CASE 
WHERE Current = 2;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server:

You would need to use dynamic SQL.  Build the string and then call sp_executesql with the string.

Edit:  Better yet, just use if statements to execute the appropriate statement and assign the value to a variable.  You should avoid dynamic SQL if possible.

Answer (score 30):

I don't believe that's possible. For one thing, query optimizers assume a specific list of table-like things in the FROM clause.

The most simple workaround that I can think of would be a UNION between the two tables:

```
SELECT  md5
FROM    hr
WHERE   @clienttype = 'Employee'
AND     current = 2
UNION
SELECT  md5
FROM    other
WHERE   @clienttype = 'Member'
AND     current = 2;
```

Only one half of the UNION could be True, given the @clienttype predicate.

Comment: I usually would write an if statement, but when using this strategy combined with an 'insert into' it saves me from having to write the insert portion multiple times, love this solution thanks, will be doing it this way from now on when possible. :)

Comment: Just be aware that the `WHERE` condition gets executed for each row in the table. So it may not be an option if the condition is a bit more complicated and there are millions of rows.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't pick a table to query using a CASE statement.  CASE statements only go within expressions, such as for a column's value or as part of your WHERE expression.

This should do it, if you are looking for just one value:

```
IF @ClientType = 'Employee' BEGIN
    SET @Source = (SELECT Md5 FROM HR WHERE Current = 2)
END
ELSE IF @ClientType = 'Member' BEGIN
    SET @Source = (SELECT Md5 FROM Other WHERE Current = 2)
END
```

Comment: As "long handed" as this is, it's the approach I'd take (but no votes left :-/). I'd much rather use a tool to generate the SQL statically (which is what, 3 lines of Ruby or 1 line of Perl? :-) vs. dealing with dynamic SQL (when I _need_ dynamic SQL, I find nothing but loathing for needing dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify what SQL backend you're going against, this will be hard to properly answer....

As far as I can tell, you will not be able to do this neither against MS SQL Server, nor against Interbase/Firebird. I can't speak for other backend servers, though...

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty safe to say the answer is no way. And that's regardless of SQL dialect.