# Is it possible to use a CASE WHEN expression in a FROM clause in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Context**

Using Oracle 12c Standard Edition (whose licensing model does not allow to use Table Partitions).

**Goal**

Use that inside a trigger to dispatch rows dynamically to different tables.

**Example**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger TRG_DISPATCH
  instead of insert or update on MY_VIEW
  for each row

DECLARE
  partition_id SIMPLE_INTEGER ;

BEGIN
  partition_id := 1 ;

  insert into
    case
      when partition_id = 1 then "my_table_1"
      when partition_id = 2 then "my_table_2"
    end ( "id", "code", "msg" )
  values
    ( :new."id", :new."code", :new."msg" )
  ;
END ;
/
```

**Note**
I *already* know [this cannot be achieved using Microsoft SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646334/is-it-possible-to-use-a-case-statement-in-a-sql-from-clause) but all RDBMS are not equal.

Comment: I think you need a case with two different insert statements.

Comment: @jarlh Hey mate, hope you are doing good. Regarding your suggestion, yes, It world work, but it would be good to know why you think to use a CASE expression here? I think otherwise, and there is already an answer to what I am directing to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, why not just use the built-in partitioning functionality in Oracle?  Much easier.

Oracle supports `insert first`:

```
insert first
    when partition_id = 1 then
        into my_table_1( "id", "code", "msg" )
            values ( :new."id", :new."code", :new."msg" )
    when partition_id = 2 then
        into my_table_2( "id", "code", "msg" )
            values ( :new."id", :new."code", :new."msg" );
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to explain why we're not using table partitions.

Comment: @Gordon Mate, thanks for bringing `insert first` out of grave ;-) IIRC, I last used it some...oh, I guess long ago :-) An upvote as usual