# Conditional from in sql query

Tags: sql

I am writing here some pseudo sql (independent of any DBMS), just to see if this is possible, and what other solutions would you suggest.

```
select 
    sb.field
from 
    case 1
        subquery1 as sb
    case 2
        subquery2 as sb
```

Is this possible? if not is there any workaround to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: with what is your case value (1, 2) compared, to see that it applies or not? Or should both cases apply at the same time?

Comment: Check out the answers at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646334/is-it-possible-to-use-a-case-statement-in-a-sql-from-clause

Answer (score 2):

You can use expressions in the where clause to turn off certain subqueries. Most RDBMS will optimize away queries with where clauses which are always false. This will only work if the two subqueries have the same fields.

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM (
    SELECT <sub1> FROM table1 WHERE <expression which is true if you want sub1>
    UNION 
    SELECT <sub2> FROM table2 WHERE <expression which is true if you want sub2>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to select from a dynamic table. The only way would be a dynamic sql which I do not recommend. Instead you can make a case statement and write your queries for each case in there. Of course, that is only if you have a reasonable amount of options.